# How to arrange a weekly schedule in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to put my schedule into org-mode, so that I can see my classes in the agenda.  I have different classes, repeated every week, all of them taking 90 minutes.  I was thinking about something like this:

```
* My schedule
** Differential equations
   <2012-10-04 Thu 11:45 +1w>--<2012-10-04 Thu 13:15 +1w>
```

However, there are two problems: I can see only the *next* instance in the agenda, and I can't see the *ending* time.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're searching for the org-diary-class, [mentionned in the Worg faq](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#org-class).

Your exemple would then be (assuming classes end on December 20th) :

```
** 11:45-13:15 Differential equations
   <%%(org-diary-class 10 4 2012 12 20 2012 2)>
```

You can add weeks where there are no classes after the last number (which is 2 for tuesday).

If you don't like having the time in the headline, you can use :

```
%%(org-diary-class 10 04 2012 12 20 2012 2) 11:45-13:15 Differential Equations
```

Last time I checked, it required %% not to be indented, so I guess each of these awesome solutions have their slight drawback.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464598/org-mode-schedule-weekly-event-for-a-period/6774553#6774553